# toggling a set of hotkeys with Autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I have `toggle` variable outside of `#IfWinActive` block but the variable is not initialized with the `#IfWinActive` block. How can I toggle a set of hotkeys?

```
toggle := false
f12::
  toggle:=!toggle
  SendInput {F12}
  return

#IfWinActive ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
    ;toggle := false ;this doesn't do anything either
    if (toggle) {
      ^a::SendInput {HOME}
    }

#IfWinActive
```

Comment: You can't assign normal hotkeys inside conditional blocks, and you don't have to. Just place your hotkeys directly below `#IfWinActive ...`. They will only be triggered when Chrome is active.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your first statement? Because I know that you could [toggle some hotkeys using another key](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/41206-modal-vim/) (e.g. CapsLock) and I want to do this. I do not want my keys to because triggered just be Chrome is active. If you see my intention, I am trying to trigger vim keys when I press F12 and open up Developer Tool.

Comment: He is saying that you cannot put your hotkey `^a::SendInput` within a conditional (`if` in your case). You must define the hotkey outside of the conditional, then handle your toggle variable within that.

Comment: Could you show me how to handle my toggle variable? Or a link please?

Comment: You can have a look at this post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24389178/how-to-toggle-keyboard-mapping-in-autohotkey/24394721#24394721

Comment: Thanks @RobertIlbrink. Just what I was looking for. Marking this question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code.

```
; [^ = Ctrl] [+ = Shift] [! = Alt] [# = Win]
#SingleInstance Force

Mode := 0
GroupAdd, Browser, ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1 ; Chrome or Iron
;GroupAdd, Browser, ahk_class IEFrame            ; Internet Explorer
;GroupAdd, Browser, ahk_class MozillaWindowClass ; FireFox
;GroupAdd, Browser, ahk_class ApplicationFrameWindow ; Edge

f12::
mode:=!mode ;not! toggle
return

#If mode ; All hotkeys below this line will only work, if mode is true and Browser is active.
^a::
If WinActive("ahk_group Browser")
{
SendInput {HOME}
} else {
send ^a
mode := 0
}
return

q::
If WinActive("ahk_group Browser")
{
send 1
} else {
send q
mode := 0
}
return

w::
If WinActive("ahk_group Browser")
{
send 2
} else {
send w
mode := 0
}
return

#If
```